# Fitting a transition + circle + transition curve to a set of measured points

Tags: geometry, curve-fitting, computational-geometry, numerical-methods

I am dealing with a reverse-engineering problem regarding road geometry and estimation of design conditions.

Suppose you have a set of points obtained from the measurement of positions of a road. This road has straight sections as well as curve sections. Straight sections are, of course, represented by lines, and curves are represented by circles of unknown center and radius. There are, as well, transition sections, which may be clothoids / Euler spirals or any other usual track transition curve. A representation of the track may look like this:
[image: Track measured positions]
We know in advance that the road / track was designed taking this transition + circle + transition principle into account for every curve, yet we only have the measurement points, and the goal is to find the parameters describing every curve on the track, this is, the transition parameters as well as the circle's center and radius.

I have written some code using a nonlinear optimization algorithm, where a user can select start and end points and fit a circle that to the arc section between them, as it shows in next figure:
[image: Fitted circle in curve]
However, I don't find a suitable way to take the transition into account. After giving it some thought I came to think that this s because, given a set of discrete points -with their measurement error- representing a full curve, it is not entirely clear where to consider it "begins" and where it "ends" and, moreover, it is less clear where to consider the transition, the proper circle and the exit transition "begin" and "end".

Is there any work on this subject which I may have missed? is there a proper way to fit the whole transition + curve + transition structure into the set of points?

Comment: Your data points seem by far too sparse for any detection of the transition sections, and even any reliable/accurate fitting of the circles ! Though it is not possible to see the exact point density nor noise amplitude from the figures.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Sorry, that is some information I could have included. The dotted line representation is clearly not suitable to indicate the point density. Measurements were taken on a railway line at a sampling frequency of 20 GPS positions per second. The exact geographical positions per distance unit is not unique, because speed was not constant, but since maximum speed was 80 km/h (22.22 m/s), thus having, in the worst scenario, a sample  every 90 cm (approximately). There are very few noisy bits which probably will be supressed and interpolated because they throw gigantic curvature values.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Also, in the figures, geographical coordinates have been converted to cartesian, yet this is not mandatory. Do you think such a density (assume a sample every 90 cm, in the worst scenario) is enough for the geometry estimation?

Comment: What is the typical length of a clothoid section ? How accurate are the measurement ?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there's no method to fit a sequence clothoid1-circle-clothoid2 into a given set of points.

Basic facts are that two points define a straight, and three points define a unique circle.

The clothoid is far more complex, because you need: The parameter **A**, the final radius **Rf**, an initial point **px,py**, the radius **Ri** at that point, and the tangent **T** (angle with X-axis) at that point.

These are 5 data you may use to find the solution.

Due to clothoid coords are calculated by expanded Fresnel integrals (see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3359006/688039 a little explanation), and then apply a translation & rotation, there's no an easy way to fit this spiral into a set of given points.

When I've had to deal with your issue, what I've done is:

1. Calculate the radius for triplets of consecutive points: p1p2p3, p2p3p4, p3p4p5, etc
2. Observe the sequence of radius. Similar values mean a circle, increasing/decreasing values mean a clothoid; Big values would mean a straight.
3. For each basic element (line, circle) find the most probably characteristics (angles, vertices, radius) by hand or by some regression method. Many times the common sense is the best.
4. For a spiral you may start with aproximated values, taken from the adjacent elements. These values may very well be the initial angle and point, and the initial and final radius. Then you need to iterate, playing with Fresnel and 'space change' until you find a "good" parameter **A**. Then repeat with small differences in the other values, those you took from adjacents.
5. Make the changes you consider as good. For example, many values (A, radius) use to be  integers, without decimals, just because it was easier for the designer to type.

If you can make a small applet to do these steps then it's enough. Using a typical roads software helps, but doesn't avoid you the iteration process.

Comment: Okay, that's a great answer and there are several ideas I'll take from it. Would you use a filter (moving average, Savitzky-Golay or such) or some data-softening method prior to calculating the radius for consecutive triplets?

Comment: I my opinion best data is raw data. There are errors in the data itself, and you can't know in advance all types of source of errors. So best fit is the one that minimizes final differences between data and estimated geometry.

Comment: Before attempting anything, I think that one must check if there is sufficient accurate data available (which I doubt).

Comment: There is no theoretical impossibility in fitting clothoids, you have to add relevant parameters to the geometric model (such as the positions of the starting/ending points), and use a general minimizer. But you can expect that the accuracy be dramatically low.

Answer (score 1):

If the points are dense compared to the effective radii of curvature, estimate the local curvature by least square fitting of a circle on a small number of points, taking into account that the curvature is most of the time zero.

You will obtain a plot with constant values and ramps that connect them. You can use an estimate of the slope at the inflection points to figure out the transition points.

Comment: just stumbled upon [this patent](https://patents.google.com/patent/US20090144331A1/en) which seems to be related. they seem to be doing what you're suggesting here. FYI.